# Issue using go-sqlmock and inserting arguments into mock queries

Tags: go, go-sqlmock

I am trying to mock my query functions using go-sqlmock & replicate the database table similarly. However, I am not getting the results that I expect. The query is not behaving as it should, arguments are not being inserted into the query & the actual result is incorrect. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the function & the query I am mocking:

```
func (y *YumDatabase) getTransactionId(pkg string) (int, error) {
    var id int

    queryForTid := "SELECT tid FROM trans_cmdline WHERE cmdline LIKE '%install " + pkg + "%' ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 1"
    row := y.db.QueryRow(queryForTid)
    switch err := row.Scan(&id); err {
    case sql.ErrNoRows:
        fmt.Println("No rows were returned")
        return 0, err
    case nil:
        return id, nil
    default:
        return 0, err
    }
}
```

And this is the mock test function:

```
func TestGetTransactionId(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("err not expected: %v", err)
    }
    pkg := "tcpdump"
    rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"tid"}).AddRow("1").AddRow("3")
    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT tid FROM trans_cmdline WHERE cmdline LIKE '%install " + pkg + "%' ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 1").WillReturnRows(rows)

    mockdb := &YumDatabase{
        db: db,
    }

    got, err := mockdb.getTransactionId("tcpdump")
    assert.Equal(t, 3, got)
}
```

If the above worked as expected, I would get back '3' in 'got' but instead I get back '1'

Secondly, is it possible to change Rows to the following:

```
rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"tid", "cmdline"}).AddRow("1", "install test").AddRow("3", "delete test2")
```

And actually do the comparison "WHERE cmdline LIKE '%install XYZ%'", because I tried this and I got back the following error (all of the main code builds & works including the queries, so this is an issue with the mock code I've wrote I'm guessing):

```
error sql: expected 2 destination arguments in Scan, not 1
```

I expect to see the highest tid returned from the SQL query, not the first one specified in "AddRow", and I expect the query to implement a check of the "cmdline" row from the mocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed your requirement in this way. First, let me share the code, then, I'll walk you through all of the relevant changes. The code is contained in two files: `repo.go` and `repo_test.go`.

#### `repo.go` file

```golang
package repo

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

func GetTransactionId(db *sql.DB, pkg string) (int, error) {
    var id int
    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT tid FROM trans_cmdline WHERE cmdline LIKE '%install $1%' ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 1", pkg)
    switch err := row.Scan(&id); err {
    case sql.ErrNoRows:
        fmt.Println("No rows were returned")
        return 0, err
    case nil:
        return id, nil
    default:
        return 0, err
    }
}
```

Here, there are two small improvements:

1. The `*sql.DB` passed in as a parameter. As suggested by the best practices, **Functions are first-class citizens**. That's why I prefer to stick to them whenever possible.
2. I used the prepared statement to pass in the argument of the query. Not a simple string concatenation. Thanks to this, it's easier to intercept the arguments passed to the query and set up expectations over them

Now let's switch to the test code.

#### `repo_test.go` file

```golang
package repo

import (
    "database/sql"
    "testing"

    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestGetTransactionId(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New(sqlmock.QueryMatcherOption(sqlmock.QueryMatcherEqual))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("err not expected while opening mock db, %v", err)
    }
    t.Run("HappyPath", func(t *testing.T) {
        rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"tid"}).AddRow("1")
        mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT tid FROM trans_cmdline WHERE cmdline LIKE '%install $1%' ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 1").
            WithArgs("tcpdump").
            WillReturnRows(rows)

        got, err := GetTransactionId(db, "tcpdump")

        assert.Equal(t, 1, got)
        assert.Nil(t, err)
    })

    t.Run("NoRowsReturned", func(t *testing.T) {
        mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT tid FROM trans_cmdline WHERE cmdline LIKE '%install $1%' ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 1").
            WithArgs("tcpdump").
            WillReturnError(sql.ErrNoRows)

        got, err := GetTransactionId(db, "tcpdump")

        assert.Equal(t, 0, got)
        assert.Equal(t, sql.ErrNoRows, err)
    })
}
```

Here, there are more changes that you need to be aware of:

1. While instantiating the `db` and `mock`, you should pass the `sqlmock.QueryMatcherEqual` as an argument to. Thanks to this, it'll exactly match queries.
2. The `ExpectQuery` method now used the prepared statement feature and expects one argument (e.g. `tcpdump` in this case).
3. Refactored the assertions to take advantage of the `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` package.

I hope that this helps you in solving your issue, let me know!